# Strange ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

The following code executes without error and produces the expected.

```
SELECT s.product_ID, s.price, s.quantity, d.wholesale_ID
      FROM
        (
          SELECT product_ID, MIN(min_price) as price, quantity
          FROM
            (
              SELECT SUM(ci.quantity) as quantity, MIN(d.price) as min_price, ci.product_ID as product_ID, wholesale_ID
                FROM "Customer order" co,
                      "CO Item" ci,
                      deal d
                WHERE co.processed   = 0
                  AND co.ID          = ci.order_ID
                  AND d.product_ID   = ci.product_ID
             GROUP BY ci.product_ID, d.wholesale_ID
             ORDER BY ci.product_ID
            )
          GROUP BY product_ID, quantity
          ORDER BY product_ID
        ) s,
        deal d
      WHERE s.product_ID = d.product_ID
        AND s.price      = d.price
      ORDER BY d.wholesale_ID
```

When I try to compile it into a procedure as a cursor, I get 'ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis' error. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE createWholesaleOrders IS
  CURSOR Curser IS(
      SELECT s.product_ID, s.price, s.quantity, d.wholesale_ID
      FROM
        (
          SELECT product_ID, MIN(min_price) as price, quantity
          FROM
            (
              SELECT SUM(ci.quantity) as quantity, MIN(d.price) as min_price, ci.product_ID as product_ID, wholesale_ID
                FROM "Customer order" co,
                      "CO Item" ci,
                      deal d
                WHERE co.processed   = 0
                  AND co.ID          = ci.order_ID
                  AND d.product_ID   = ci.product_ID
             GROUP BY ci.product_ID, d.wholesale_ID
             ORDER BY ci.product_ID
            )
          GROUP BY product_ID, quantity
          ORDER BY product_ID
        ) s,
        deal d
      WHERE s.product_ID = d.product_ID
        AND s.price      = d.price
      ORDER BY d.wholesale_ID -- < MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS HERE
      );

  Pointer Curser%rowtype;
  current_wholesale NUMBER := -1;
  current_order     NUMBER := -1;
BEGIN
   OPEN Curser;
  LOOP
FETCH Curser INTO Pointer;
EXIT WHEN Curser%NOTFOUND;

IF current_wholesale != Pointer.wholesale_ID THEN
  current_order     := wholesale_order_sq.NEXTVAL;
  INSERT INTO "Wholesale order" (ID, wholesale_ID, "date") VALUES(current_order, Pointer.wholesale_ID, sysdate);
  current_wholesale := Pointer.wholesale_ID;
END IF;

INSERT INTO "WO Item" (ID, order_ID, product_ID, quantity, price)
                VALUES(wo_item_sq.NEXTVAL, current_order, Pointer.product_ID, Pointer.quantity, Pointer.price);

 UPDATE "CO Item"
   SET "CO Item"."wholesale-order_ID" = current_order
 WHERE "CO Item".order_ID IN (
                                SELECT "Customer order".ID
                                  FROM "Customer order"
                                 WHERE "Customer order".processed = 0
                             )
   AND "CO Item".product_ID = Pointer.product_ID;
END LOOP;
UPDATE "Customer order"
 SET processed = 1
 WHERE processed = 0;
END;
```

Updated to include full code. There should be no errors on other places.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about parens around the select statement.

Comment: As an aside, the ORDER BY clauses in the inline view "s" are pointless.

Comment: @DCookie Point taken. They were introduced as a sub-query debug "function".

Comment: When compiling the procedure you may get an error around a cursor at the place you call it. What does the code look like where you open and fetch from the cursor? Are you looping through it?

Comment: @Ben Updated to include full code.

Comment: Just for the files: you _did_ try to remove the bracing parenthesis after the `IS`, didn't you? They are not required, although as @dcookie points out they are usually not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For whatever reason, the compiler does not accept the parens around the select in this cursor (as originally suggested by a_horse_with_no_name), although there is nothing inherently wrong with it as the following code compiles fine for me:

```
create or replace
procedure test is
cursor c is (select 1 from dual);
begin
null;
end;
```

However, if I remove the parens in your code, it does compile and refuses to compile for me otherwise.  Sounds like a compiler bug to me.